# Fllutter - 3 widgets inside row, align right last one

Tags: flutter, layout, alignment, row

Layout is defined as foollows:

```
Flexible(child: new Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                            child: Text(categoryIcon,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                    fontFamily: 'Fontawesome',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))),
                        Flexible(
                            child: Text(categoryName,
                                maxLines: 3,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))),

                        Text("#33088",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black26,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))

                      ]),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 3.0, left: 8.0, top: 10.0, right: 5.0),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      child: Text(title,
                          maxLines: 3,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 16)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 3.0, left: 8.0, top: 10.0, right: 5.0),
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      child: new Text(address,
                          style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 10.0, left: 8.0, top: 10.0, right: 5.0),
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      child: Padding(
                        child: new Text("⬤  " + statusName,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                color: HexColor(statusColor))),
                        padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 8.0, top: 0.0),
                      ),
                      visible: type == ResponseMessageType.MESSAGE_TYPE_EVENT ||
                          type == ResponseMessageType.MESSAGE_TYPE_MY_EVENT,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ));
```

I am getting result:

[image]

So always when second row widget (label) is text wrapped, label is aligned right, if not, label is not aligned at all. If I try:

```
Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                            child: Text(categoryIcon,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                    fontFamily: 'Fontawesome',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))),
                        Flexible(
                            child: Text(categoryName,
                                maxLines: 3,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))),
                        Spacer(),

                        Text("#33088",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black26,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))

                      ])
```

I am getting label line wrap incorrectly and still not right aligned label when label text is not wrapped:

[image]

I need my list to look as on the first picture, but label "#33088" needs to be always right aligned, no matter if category label is wrapped or not. Category label needs to be wrapped when there's no remaining space, taken also by "#33088" label.

How to do that correctly?

[edit]

Partially based on below responses, it looks that worked:

```
Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                                categoryIcon,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue, fontFamily: 'Fontawesome', fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))),

                            Flexible(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: Text(categoryName,
                                          maxLines: 3,
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),

                        Visibility(
                          visible: type == ResponseMessageType.MESSAGE_TYPE_EVENT,
                          child: Expanded(
                            flex: 0,
                            child: Text("#" + id, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black26, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                          ),
                        )

                      ])
```

(sorry, some logic included now). But I am not happy with this, especially, I don't understand why do I need this:

```
Flexible(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Flexible(
                                      child: Text(categoryName,
                                          maxLines: 3,
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
```

If I put single `Flexible` instead:

```
Flexible(
          child: Text(categoryName,
          maxLines: 3,
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
        )
```

Again #id label is not aligned. With row containing single Flexible, wrapped again with Flexible, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Check Border Shadow and Elevation Attributes I hope you'll find your answer

Comment: Any details what do you mean? You misunderstood my question, I don't mean card elevation, I mean labels inside it

Comment: Okey I now understand your question your flexible widget holds place as inside of its child so your label's takes the remaining place thats why always changes if you want your label stays always right corner you should take your label inside of a sized box widget and size them staticly that will work but not a perfect solution :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.flash_on,
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod",
                            maxLines: 3,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.lightBlue,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "#33088",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black26,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Flexible(child: new Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded( // here
```

Try using expanded

Answer (score 0):

In a row wrap your first three widgets with expanded(each Widget Wrap with expanded) and then fourth widget will automatically align to the right

and your code will look like

```
Flexible(child: new Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                                      child: Padding(
                    child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                          child: Text(categoryIcon,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                  fontFamily: 'Fontawesome',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))),
                      Flexible(
                          child: Text(categoryName,
                              maxLines: 3,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))),

                      Text("#33088",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black26,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal))

                    ]),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 3.0, left: 8.0, top: 10.0, right: 5.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                                      child: Padding(
                    child: Text(title,
                        maxLines: 3,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 16)),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 3.0, left: 8.0, top: 10.0, right: 5.0),
                  ),
                ),

                Expanded(
                                      child: Padding(
                    child: new Text(address,
                        style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        bottom: 10.0, left: 8.0, top: 10.0, right: 5.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  child: Padding(
                    child: new Text("⬤  " + statusName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            color: HexColor(statusColor))),
                    padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 8.0, top: 0.0),
                  ),
                  visible: type == ResponseMessageType.MESSAGE_TYPE_EVENT ||
                      type == ResponseMessageType.MESSAGE_TYPE_MY_EVENT,
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),
```